# Accessing ListView Evals from code behind. getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, stored-procedures, eval

Like many other people I am trying assign an Eval value to a label in a table outside of a ListView. I am using a stored procedure that returns monthly rainfall amounts for sites throughout the city. The field I want is not one of the passed parameters: @reqyear and @reqLocation. It is a calculated field, Total, which  shows up fine in the ListView as a Eval, but I cannot figure out how to access it directly in code behind so I am using an ItemDataBound method to find the control then assign it. Several snipets are readily found in the boards. So I tried each one that seemed applicable and all return an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. I am trying to assign Eval("Total") to the label id MTotal. The page runs fine without the code needed for label assignment. Perhaps, I am going about the label assignment the wrong way and can get the field I want without using the Eval in the ListView.

Any advice is appreciated.

```
code behind:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;



namespace WebApplication1.OUTREACH.rainfall
{
    public partial class monthlyRF : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            reqyear.Items.Clear();


            for (int i = DateTime.Now.Year; i != 1998; i--)
            {
                reqyear.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }

            reqLocation.SelectedValue = "2";
        }

        String strConnString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TelogerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.spBWSC_GetTrendDataMonthly";          
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@req_Location", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reqLocation.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@req_year", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reqyear.Text;         
        cmd.Connection = con;


        try
        {
            con.Open();
            ListView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ListView1.DataBind();

            yearLabel.Text = reqyear.Text;


            switch (cmd.Parameters["@Req_Location"].Value.ToString())
            {
                case "2":
                    site_nameLabel.Text = "Union Park";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    site_nameLabel.Text = "Roslindale";
                    break;
                case "4":
                    site_nameLabel.Text = "Dorch-Adams";
                    break;
                case "5":
                    site_nameLabel.Text = "Allston";
                    break;
                case "6":
                    site_nameLabel.Text = "Charlestown";
                    break;
                case "7":
                    site_nameLabel.Text = "Longwood";
                    break;
                case "8":
                    site_nameLabel.Text = "Hyde Park";
                    break;
                case "9":
                    site_nameLabel.Text = "Dorch-Talbot";
                    break;

            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

        }


    }


    protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Label Total_lbl;
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            Total_lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Total_lbl");

            DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
            string sTotal = rowView["Total"].ToString();
            MTotal.Text = sTotal;

        }
    }


        }
```

}

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="monthlyRF.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.OUTREACH.rainfall.monthlyRF" enableEventValidation="false" EnableViewState="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="reqLocation" runat="server" Font-Italic="False" 
    Height="100px" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="590px">
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Union Park</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Roslindale</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Dorch-Adams</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Allston</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">Charlestown</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="7">Longwood</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="8">Hyde Park</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="9">Dorch_Talbot</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>



<asp:DropDownList ID="reqyear" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit"  />
 <br />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TelogerConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="spBWSC_GetTrendDataMonthly" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="reqyear" Name="req_year" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="reqLocation" Name="req_Location" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>

<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="590px" style="margin-top: 25px;">
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="site_nameLabel" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;"><asp:Label ID="yearLabel" runat="server"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="site_name, Total, month, monthly_total" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">


    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table runat="server" style="">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    No data was returned.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="border: 1px solid black;" >
                      <td style="width:245px;">
                 <asp:Label ID="Total_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Total") %>' /></td><td><asp:Label ID="monthLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("month") %>' />
            </td>
             <td style="text-align:right; width:245px;">
                <asp:Label ID="TotalLabel"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("monthly_total", "{0:0.00}") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" width="590px">
                        <tr id="header1" runat="server" style="">


                            <th style="text-align:left;" runat="server">
                                Month</th>

                            <th style="text-align:right;" runat="server">
                                Rainfall (in.)</th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">

                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" style="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tfoot>
            <tr >
            <td colspan="2">this is the listview footer</td>

            </tr>

            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>      
</asp:ListView>
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="590px" style="margin-top: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td>first cell
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;"><asp:Label ID="MTotal" runat="server" Text="Label"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that the line

```
DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
```

is the problem here. Set a breakpoint on that line and investigate what type you are getting there.

Where type conversion is done using the as keyword, a failure to carry out the conversion will return null rather than an exception, so the subsequent call to the ["Total"] indexer is being carried out on a null reference.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion, unfortunately, that line of code never gets executed. It's breaking at the 'throw ex;' in the catch statement. Upon commenting that line out, one row of data is returned but the Total remains unassigned.

Comment: Right, that means that something in the try block above it is causing the problem. MSDN docs suggest that parameter names are not case sensitive, so the fact that you declare a parameter called 'req_Location' and then access its value using 'Req_Location' shouldn't matter, although it's not ideal. Place the breakpoint at the top of the try block, and see what causes the exception to be raised. Finally, 'throw ex' is rarely a good idea, as it destroys the stack trace. Just 'throw' will suffice.